# Anti-concentration of gaussian variable

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, gaussian

Let $X$ be $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ gaussian. Its expectation $\mu$ is positive. Can we derive a lower bound on
$$\mathbb{P}(X\geq\epsilon)\geq g(\epsilon,\mu,\sigma) \text{ where } \epsilon\leq\mu$$
such that

1. $g$ is decreasing along with $\epsilon$ and
2. $g$ depends on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ as well?

Comment: What other constraints do you put on $g$? Otherwise one could take $ g (\epsilon) := \mathbb{P}( X \geq \epsilon)$ and correctly claim that it is a valid lower bound.

Comment: hi! explicit function on $\epsilon$, $\mu,\sigma$

Comment: Why do you write $g(\epsilon)$ if you explicitly mean $g(\epsilon, \mu, \sigma)$?

Comment: yes right, I should write $g(\epsilon,\mu,\sigma)$

Comment: Do you prefer $\epsilon$ to $\varepsilon$, or are you unaware of the alternative? (Sometimes when adding corrections of other things in MathJax I've changed $\epsilon$ to $\varepsilon$ and so far no one has expressed an objection. The former seems to me too much like $\in.$ In Wikipedia articles I often change $\epsilon$ to $\varepsilon$ and $\phi$ to $\varphi.$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\vpi\varphi$By shifting and rescaling, without loss of generality $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. Then many lower bounds on $P(X\ge t)$ are available in the form of algebraic expressions in terms of $t$ and $\vpi(t)$, where $\vpi$ is the standard normal density. E.g., one has
$$P(X\ge t)>p(t):=\frac{t\vpi(t)}{1+t^2}$$
for $t>0$; see e.g. the [Laplace continued fraction (16)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2333015?origin=JSTOR-pdf) for $R(t):=P(X\ge t)/\vpi(t)$. Note that $p(t)$ is decreasing in $t\ge t_*:=\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}=0.643\ldots$.

For $t\in(0,t_*]$, one can use the following:
$$P(X\ge t)=\frac12-\int_0^t du\,\vpi(u)
=\frac12-\vpi(0)\int_0^t du\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-u^2/2)^k}{k!} \\ 
=\frac12-\vpi(0)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k t^{2k+1}}{k!(2k+1)2^k}>l_{2m}(t)
:=\frac12-\vpi(0)\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\frac{(-1)^k t^{2k+1}}{k!(2k+1)2^k}$$
for any $m=0,1,\dots$; actually, the inequality $P(X\ge t)>l_{2m}(t)$ holds for all real $t>0$. In particular, $l_0(t)=\frac12-\vpi(0)t$ and $l_2(t)=\frac12-\vpi(0)(t-t^3/6+t^5/40)$.
Alternatively, for $t\in[0,t_*]$ one can use formula (7) from the linked paper.

---

As an illustration, below are graphs

- $\{(t,P(X\ge t))\colon 0<t<2\}$ (black);
- $\{(t,\max[l_0(t),p(t)])\colon 0<t<2\}$ (green);
- $\{(t,p(t))\colon 0<t<2\}$ (dotted blue and then green);
- $\{(t,l_0(t))\colon 0<t<2\}$ (green and then dotted red);
- $\Big\{\Big(t,\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2e}\,t}2\Big)\colon 0<t<t_0\Big\}$ for some $t_0\in(1,2)$ (orange), regarding the lower bound $1-\sqrt{2e}\,t$ on $P(|X|\ge t)=2P(X\ge t)$ at the end of the [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/447074/36721);
- $\Big\{\Big(t,\dfrac{\max[l_2(t),p(t)]}{P(X\ge t)}\Big)\colon 0<t<6\Big\}$ (magenta).

[image]

[image]

We see that the lower bound $\max[l_2(t),p(t)]$ on $P(X\ge t)$ is close to $P(X\ge t)$ for all real $t>0$ and very close to $P(X\ge t)$ for $t\in(0,1]$ and for large $t$.

Using mentioned results, we can get however close (even though somewhat more complicated) lower (and upper bounds) on $P(X\ge t)$.

---

To get lower bounds on $P(X\ge t)$ for real $t<0$, simply write $P(X\ge t)=1-P(X\le t)=1-P(X\ge|t|)$ and then use upper bounds on $1-P(X\ge|t|)$ from the cited paper and/or the inequality $P(X\ge|t|)<l_{2m+1}(|t|)$ for $m=0,1,\dots$. This way, you e.g. get
$$P(X\ge t)>1-\min\Big(\frac{\vpi(t)}{|t|},l_{2m+1}(|t|)\Big)$$
for real $t<0$.

Comment: Thank you  very much. But would need $P(X>=t)>=…$ when t is negative..I revised my question to be more specific

Comment: @M.K : This matter has now been addressed as well, as the end of the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for the bounds! I have some more questions: (1) where could I find the source of $P(x\ge t)\ge \frac{t\phi(t)}{1+t^2}$ (2) why $\int_0^t du\,\phi(u) = \phi(0)\int_0^t du\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-u^2/2)^k}{k!}$? Could you recommend materials to me so that I can get familiar about these formulas? and I also found it is difficult for myself to search online about these bounds, I did not find in any book also. According to your experience, are there some list of papers for example the one that you linked, that beyond books but people should know? many thanks in advance.

Comment: @M.K : (i) A source for $P(X\ge t)>p(t):=\dfrac{t\varphi(t)}{1+t^2}$ is, as stated in the answer, formula (16) in the linked paper by Shenton. Taking the second convergent, $\phi_2=\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1t}$, of the continued fraction in that formula, we get (cf. (19) in that paper) $P(X\ge t)/\varphi(t)=R(t)>\phi_2=\dfrac t{1+t^2}$. (ii) Write $\varphi(u)=\varphi(0)e^{-u^2/2}$; then expand $e^{-u^2/2}$ into powers of $(-u^2/2)$; then integrate. Please let me know if further details are needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are various papers in the literature regarding anti-concentration in *polynomials* of Gaussian random variables.
I'll point you to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.05992.pdf), which discusses a few other papers as well.
The result (discussed in that paper) below is due to Carbery and Wright.

> There exists a universal positive constant $C$
> such that the following holds. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be any degree $d$ polynomial, and let $\mu$ denote any log-concave measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For every $\epsilon > 0$:
> $$\Pr_{x\sim \mu}[|f(x)| \leq \epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mu}[|f (x)|]] \leq C_d \epsilon^{1/d}.$$

Here, "log concave" means it admits a density with a concave logarithm, i.e. of the form $\exp(-V(x))$ for $V(x)$ convex.
Gaussians are of this form.
Note that this result does not indicate how large the constant $C_d$ is, though the linked paper has pointers to things that work out the constant in simpler cases.
For example, the main result of that paper is

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}$ be any non-negative degree two polynomial. For every $\epsilon > 0$:
> $$\Pr_{x\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_n)}[f(x) \leq \epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}_x[f(x)]] \leq (2e \epsilon)^{1/2}$$

One can apply this to $f(x) = x^2$ and rearrange algebraically to get that

$$\Pr_{x\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)}[|x| \leq \sqrt{\epsilon} \sigma] \leq (2e\epsilon)^{1/2},$$

or equivalently

$$\forall t > 0 : \Pr_{x\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)}[|x| > t\sigma] \geq 1 - \sqrt{2e}t.$$